# VBA: Refresh Power query and subsequently update pivot tables

Tags: vba, pivot-table, powerquery

I have an Excel file that comprises a sheet "DATA", which contains data extracted using a Power Query, and three other sheets containing pivot tables that are all dependent on these extracted data in "DATA".

I wantto create a VBA that (1) automatically refreshes/reruns the Power Query specified above when the Excel file is opened and (2) subsequently updates the three pivot tables to mirror the updated data.

I have made several attempts and looked for similar questions on stackoverflow, but without succeeding:
While it was possible for me to refresh the data by refreshing the connection, the Pivot tables were not updated accordingly.

One VBA code that, among others, did not yield the desired results (i.e. subsequently updating the Pivot table) is:

```
Sub test()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim pt As PivotTable

'ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll 'make sure the refresh in bg property is false for all connections
 ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Name of Query").Refresh
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each pt In ws.PivotTables
        pt.RefreshTable
    Next pt
Next ws

End Sub
```

Thank you!

Comment: "did not yield the desired results": what do you mean by this: did you get an error, did nothing happen, did something unexpected happened? (http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/) It's hard to help you without knowing what's not working.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Ike. I will modify my question to clarify what I mean by desired results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must be sure that "background refresh" is set to false:

```
    Sub Refresh_All_Data_Connections()
        Dim objConnection, bBackground
            For Each objConnection In ThisWorkbook.Connections
                'Get current background-refresh value
                bBackground = objConnection.OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery
        
                'Temporarily disable background-refresh
                objConnection.OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery = False
        
                'Refresh this connection
                objConnection.refresh
        
                'Set background-refresh value back to original value
                objConnection.OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery = bBackground
            Next
    ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
    End Sub
```

Update: added refreshall to refresh all pivot tables.
Rereading your question if you just want to refresh a specific query (assuming sh is set):

```
    sh.ListObjects("Name of Table").QueryTable.refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
```

Comment: Hi Ceci. Thank you for providing an answer! Is this code sufficient to also update the Pivot tables or will I have to append this to my code specfied above. I am fairly new to VBA, so the answer to my question may seem trivial to you, my apologies.